# How to Find What a Project Inherit's It's Additional Include Directories From

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, include, projects-and-solutions

I have a project that is directly under the solution, it isn't nested in another project. Yet it has tons of values in it's "Additional Include Directories">"Inherited values":

[image]

I want to modify these, but where should I look for where these are defined?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @acid1789 I'm trying to upgrade a project from Visual Studio 2008 :O So it's understandable if all the tomes from that era have fallen to decay, if you could give an answer for Visual Studio 2015 that would at least give me a place to start looking.

Comment: They changed that entire system in VS2013.  I believe it used to be in Tools->Options->Projects & Solutions->VC++ Directories

Comment: @acid1789 So you are correct that there are default included directories there, however for no type of File do they contain the "Inherited values" in my projects, seems like there is something else these are inheriting from.

Comment: @acid1789 I've done a search across the whole project workspace and the only place I find these includes is in the *.vsprops files. I need to find out more information on what a *.vsprops file is/does...

Comment: @acid1789 So it was the properties. In the project I'm working they're just set up to be annoying, but apparently there are uses for them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35296351/2642059

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This information is coming from the properties. You can see those on a per project basis in the "Property Manager" (I've attached a picture of my "View">"Other Windows">"Property Manager" but [Assimilater has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094352/how-to-find-what-a-project-inherits-its-additional-include-directories-from/35296351?noredirect=1#comment62429460_35296351) that the location may not be consistent across Visual Studio editions.)

In your Property Manager window you'll need to find your projects properties. Find your project and open the folder for the configuration you wish to modify. Right click on: "Local settings (specific for all projects in the directory)" and select "Properties".

From there you can edit "Common Properties">"C/C++">"General"'s "Additional Include Directories". Anything added here will show up in the "Inherited values" of your projects "Additional Include Directories" dialog.

I've validated that this information is consistent on Visual Studio 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, and 2015.

You can read a more in depth piece on how to use properties here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx

[image]

Comment: In visual studio 2015 I don't have "Property Manager". The instructions don't seem to line up with the "Property Pages" that you get from right clicking on a project and going to properties, or from the icon in the "Properties Window". Can you please clarify how it's different in 2015? (I'm confused because you say you verified the information is consistent....)

Comment: Found it; appears it's not in "Other Windows" but near the bottom of the view menu >:(

Comment: @Assimilater Ugh sorry, I'll update that when I get back to a computer with Visual Studio 2015. I just tested that the "Property Manager" worked, not how it could be accessed on Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @Assimilater Hmmm... It was still in "View">"Other Windows">"Property Manager" for me.  I've attached a picture to the answer. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015. Perhaps it's different on a different edition? You're not thinking of "Properties Window" are you?

Comment: Perhaps it's because I have the professional version of visual studio that it's different. My properties window and properties manager are switched in location from yours. See: http://prntscr.com/b8pymc

Comment: In any case +1 from me :)

Comment: @Assimilater Thanks, I'm most pleased this helped someone other than myself, cause I was definitely pulling my hair out over it. I've edited again to link to your comment, thanks for the info, maybe that too will be helpful to someone.

Comment: How to apply "Right click on: "Local settings (specific for all projects in the directory)" and select "Properties"" in VS2017?